# Using Strongly Connected Components Algo as Cycle Detection

Tags: algorithm, graph

I understand that if a set of vertices are part of strongly connected components, then all those vertices within the component can reach one another; a cycle.

Now, I would like to use this fact and claim that if a graph G = (V,E) has a cycle, then that cycle MUST BE inside scc.

In other words, all cycles must be part of scc (my claim).

I cant think of any counterexample to my claim, so I would like to know if there are any cycles in a graph that are not part of scc.
Or
Is my claim, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let e = (u, v) be the edge in question. We note that is a cycle in G containing e if and only
if u is connected to v in G{e}.
Our algorithm merely runs DFS from u on G{e}, and outputs yes if v is reachable from u
and no otherwise.
This algorithm runs in linear time as DFS runs in linear time (and we only run part of the
DFS algorithm finding the component that contains u). This algorithm is clearly correct.
If u is connected to v in G{e} by some path p, we can add edge e to p to form a cycle.
Otherwise, the removal of e from G disconnects u and v.

Answer (score 12):

It's correct. If a set of vertices are in a cycle, then they are all reachable from each other (by going around the cycle), so they are an SCC by definition.

Having said that, it's not exactly a programming problem :)

Comment: thank you. well, I know that if its an SCC then it is a cycle. But I am asking if SCC algo captures ALL cycles in a graph or a select few. Like if you are a German Shepard then you are a dog. But if you are a dog then it doesnt means you are a German Shepard. My analogy

Comment: My answer was precisely worded: If a set of vertices are in a cycle, then they are in an SCC. Isn't that what you were asking? How else can I say that?

Comment: No, you are right. "If a set of vertices are in a cycle, then they are in an SCC." (singular). I just wanted to make sure that ALL CYCLES in a graph is an SCC because "If a set of vertices are in a cycle, then they are in an SCC." I was wondering if there would be a case where it is a cycle but not captured by SCC. You are saying there are none. okay thank you! what i needed

Comment: This is actually false, apparently.

Comment: @antz, what is false? That a cycle must be in an scc? Or that finding scc's is the best algorithm for cycle detection? A cycle must be in an scc, but you can detect cycles directly much faster (unless you have a lot of queries of the form "is there a cycle which includes x and y in this graph?"). That wasn't your question, though.